# Terminal set to an illegal value unable to fix

Tags: macos, shell, command-line, terminal, command

im running a Snow Leopard 10.6.8 and today i tried running Terminal when i got an error which said.
`"You are authorised to run this application
The Administrator has set your shell to and illegal value."`
I checked older posts and so far i have tried changing Terminals File Permissions,Changed /private/etc/shells to default and repaired permissions with disk utility. Does anyone know how to fix this.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like your user shell got set to an illegal value. To fix this:

1. Open System Preferences, and go to the Users and groups pane
2. Click the padlock and authenticate as an administrator
3. Right-click (or Control-click) on your user account in the sidebar, then choose Advanced Options from the shortcut menu that appears.
4. In the Advanced dialog, change your Login shell to "/bin/bash". DO NOT CHANGE ANYTHING ELSE.
5. Click OK to save the change, log out & back in, and try using Terminal again.

Answer (score 0):

The default shell for your user will be set in `/private/etc/passwd` at the end of the line starting with your username. It should be set to `/bin/bash`

Comment: I found "User Database" with a list in a format like    
    "_www:*:70:70:World Wide Web Server:/Library/WebServer:/usr/bin/false" i didnt find anything like /bin/bash

Comment: OS X does not use /private/etc/passwd for regular user accounts; it has a completely different user database.